# Error: webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.splitChunks instead?

Tags: webpack

```js
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['commons'],
  minChunks: 2
})
```

Выводит ошибку

> Error: webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed, please
>   use config.optimization.splitChunks instead?

А как теперь выносить общие модули в отдельные файлы?

Comment: в ошибке же рекомендация: please use [config.optimization.splitChunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
    ....,

    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: true,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    name: 'commons',
                    test: 'commons',
                    enforce: true,
                    minChunks: 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```